# WP7 NameOrPhoneNumber inputscope: Possible to set PhoneNumber as default?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have a textbox that takes both text and number, but numbers are mainly used. I realy like the NameOrPhoneNumber inputscope, but it would be more userfriendly if I could specify that the PhoneNumber part of this SIP is default when it opens. Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 1):

You could add a button that allows the user to switch between the two InputScopes.

The InputScope can be set in the code-behind, like this:

```
InputScope scope = new InputScope();
InputScopeName name = new InputScopeName();

name.NameValue = InputScopeNameValue.Number;
scope.Names.Add(name);

txtPhoneNumber.InputScope = scope;
```

Answer (score 1):

The InputScope enum supports a large number of formats.  You can just set the InputScope to Number.

More details can be found here.

[InputScope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.inputscopenamevalue%28v=VS.95%29.aspx)

Or you can set the scope to TelephoneNumber if you want to allow Telephone Numbers etc.